# Is sorting out some data only in ng-repeat possible, by avoiding unnecessary?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a json object inside my controller, i want to print details of user which has username:vishnu ( i want to sort from objects and print using ng-repeat).

```
        [{
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "fixing bugs",
"time": "1"
    }, {
"username": "seenu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "working on ui",
"time": "2"
  }, {
"username": "sam",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "bigiron",
"task": "working on api",
"time": "5"
    },
      {
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "timetracker",
"task": "ui designing",
"time": "1"
    }]
```

how to make it work, how should i sort?

Comment: You should sort using javascript and then print using ng-repeat. Maybe you can create another array which only has the objects with username as 'vishnu'.

Comment: what kind of sort i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="data in jsondata">
   <div ng-if="data.username=='vishnu'" >
     <b>{{data.username}}</b>
     <b>{{data.selectedProject}}</b>
     <b>{{data.task}}</b>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can try out the above code and restrict data for a single user only

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="data in jsondata | orderBy:'username' ">
   {{data.username}}
</div>
```

Given that you have list of Objects in json, as mentioned by you, you can use above code to orderBy any of the object's property, here we have ordered by 'username'.

Comment: i am not asking for a rearrangement like ordering by alphabetical, i want to show details of one user only, othe should not be displayed